# I want to duplicate an object with rig

Tags: rigging

[image]

I made two objects, blue cube and red cube, and put rigs on the objects.
The rig in red object is set parent to the rig in blue object.

I wanted to duplicate only red cube with rig.
so, in object mode, I selected rig and the red object and duplicated those.
But, the result is like 2.

How can I duplicate rig in the red cube and the red cube only?

[image]

Comment: Suggest duplicate the rig object and delete the blue one.

Comment: @brockmann: i would guess - he wanna make that a thousand times.... ;)

Comment: i just tried it ...and i didn't get the second armature copied...how did you copy?

Comment: @Chris: Yes I want to make that a thousand times ;) when I select the armature in object mode, it autometically selected together. I made the seconde amature by extrude in edit mode.

Comment: can you make a video of this?

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 objects: redCube, blueCube and one Armature, which contains 2 bones: redBone and blueBone.

Obviously if you duplicate the Armature, you will get a new Armature.001 containing 2 bones: redBone and blueBone.

To have the project work correctly you should have two different armatures, one for redcube and one for blue cube.

In this new scenario you can select the blueArmature, shift select the redArmature, go to pose mode, select the redBone and press Ctrl P > bone, to make the blueArmature child of the redBone.

Now you will be able to duplicate redCube and redArmature without creating unnecessary bones.

Comment: I don't understand this part "In this new scenario you can select the blueArmature, shift select the redArmature." When I select the blueArmature, both Armatures are selected. When I select blueArmature and shift select the redArmature, none of them is selected ;(

Comment: It's because by now you have a single armature, with 2 bones. To get the new scenario select the armature, go to edit mode, select the blueBone and press P (separate into new object). Now you will have two different armature objects, each consisting in one bone only.